# Server certificate doesn't recognize if created using openSSL

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssl

I am trying to enable SSL for my application which is connected to oracle as well as MSSQL server placed remotely.
I am using openSSL to create self-signed certificate.I basically created one RootCA certificate and then signed a certificate request using generated RootCA.
It is working fine for Oracle but when it comes to MSSQL, I am facing below issue:

1. When using sqlclient to connect to the database server, i am adding these two attribute in **DbConnectionStringBuilder** connection string.

   a.Encrypt=True

   b.TrustServerCertificate=False

In this case the connection is not being established.If I am setting TrustServerCertificate=True then it is working fine. I installed the RootCA certificate in trusted root certification authorities folder and the server certificate in personal floder using MMC Console.I went to SQL Server Configuration utility and checked the certificate tab dropdown i cannot see the certificate.

Can anyone help me out on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried marking you server cert private key as exportable?

Comment: Yes I tried with it

Comment: Please post your connection string, and please post the server certificate.

Comment: Please find the connection string code sample below

    System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = 
    new      System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder["Data Source"] = "MyServer";
    builder["integrated Security"] = true;
    builder["Initial Catalog"] = "MyDB";
    builder["Encrypt"] = "True";
    builder["TrustServerCertificate"] = "False"
    builder["User ID"] = "sa";
    builder["Password"] = "sa";